# Set a Variable in one View Controller and Access it in another View Controller based on a Button Pressed

Tags: ios, viewcontroller

I currently have 2 separate views with separate view controllers in the IB editor. Basically I want to set the value of a variable (in my case it is a float representing what I will set as the timer)  that is based on the a button that is pressed in the first view controller, then pass that variable to the second view controller. The problem I am coming up with is that since the variable set is based on UISegmentedControl that is pressed in the first view, it is not as though I can create an instance of the first class in the second class because that would not save what button was pressed. Right? 
So next I tried to set my variable in the first class as a static variable, then make my second class a subclass of the first class and access the variable that way. Unfortunately, I set the variable in the first class, but when I access it from the second (child)class, it defaults back to a value of 0. Which is not correct. It looks as though data encapsulation causes that?

In short, I just want to be able to set a variable in my viewController based on a button that was pressed, then use that variable and access it in my second viewController class.

I would also appreciate a short explanation of why accessing the variable from the child class does not work. Any part that is unclear I will do my best to clear up. Thank You in advance!

Comment: Please do some searching before you ask a question -- some version of this question is asked at least once a day on this forum. Try searching "Set a Variable in one View Controller and Access it in another View Controller" and you'll get a lot of results.

Comment: Yes thanks, I had researched it and tried it and it wasn't working that way. My questions asks why it doesn't work as stated in other questions and if there is a better way to do it than what I am currently trying.

Comment: Your problem is that you need to get a reference to the other controller, not, as you pointed out, create a new instance. How you get that reference depends on how the two controllers are related. Does one create the other (and then push or present in code), or segue to the other? As for your question about accessing a variable from a child class, you have a basic misunderstanding -- the child will have that same variable, but it will be a different instance, so it will have its own value, which will be 0 for an int or nil for an object, until you set it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better approach may be to create a class which is the data model for your common data. In this case it's just the float value for your timer.

Create an instance of the model class, and then add a property for the object in each of your view controller classes. When you instantiate the view controller, set it's property to point to the model object.

Hopefully that makes some sense?

Comment: Yes thank you! It turns out, most of my problem was due to not setting a value when initializing the static value, but thank you for the advice. I'm assuming your method is generally viewed as "better programming style" than static variables I'm trying to use when they aren't needed.

Comment: That's correct. Best to think about "where does this data belong" to arrive at an architecture decision. Especially when you see that two or more parts of your code are having to work together. Glad I could help.